# How can I get the code to wait until the file is updated?

Tags: node.js

How do you get this code to work? Brand new to node and call back functions and promises. This is a unique and specific question. I'm getting an error. It is supposed to wait for the file to change.

Code:

```
    (async () => {

    var filename1 = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads/image.png";
    var downloadanduploadpath = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads";
    var timeout = 2000;
    var fs = require('fs');
    
     function checkExistsWithTimeout(filePath, timeout) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                watcher.close();
                reject(new Error('File did not exists and was not created during the timeout.'));
            }, timeout);

            fs.access(filePath, fs.constants.R_OK, function (err) {
                if (!err) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    watcher.close();
                    resolve();
                }
            });

            var dir = path.dirname(filePath);
            var basename = path.basename(filePath);
            var watcher = fs.watch(dir, function (eventType, filename) {
                if (eventType === 'rename' && filename === basename) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    watcher.close();
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    
    //
    checkExistsWithTimeout(downloadanduploadpath,2000);
})();
```

Error:

> ```
> watcher.close();
>         ^    TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
> ```

Comment: your `watcher` variable is declare for assignment of `fs.watch`  method , while it is also used before its intialization in fs.access method 's callback. moving your `fs.watch` lines above fs.access might help.

Comment: @bron1010 Thanks. Now i get "(node:12232) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: path is not defined"

Comment: use `var path = require('path');` at the top. This is among node api core module , use for various operations regarding file path or URL path